Google Groups Access API
I have a case where a collaborator needs to create an automation in Google Cloud to access the Groups API in Google Workspace, which would be the one below:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/insert?hl=pt-br
If I release, for example, this Scope below:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member
Does this give her access only to the groups she manages or will it give her access to all CI&T Workspace groups? Can I limit access to specific groups only?
I would like to know if releasing a scope as below gives the user access only to the group in which they are admin, or to all groups in a Google Workspace domain
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/insert?hl=pt-br
